# Java Generics List Compilation error

Tags: java, generics

Why i get a compilation error  in this line String s=data.get(idx);

Update: I get **Type mismatch: cannot convert from E to String**

```
    public class Parent<E> {
        ArrayList<E> data=new ArrayList<E>();

        public void add(E d){
            data.add(d);
        }
        public List<E> getData(){
            return data;
        }
    }

    public class Child<E> extends Parent<E>{

        public void appendData(E newItem){
            super.add(newItem);
        }
        public void displayData(int idx){
            List<E> data=this.getData();
            **String s=data.get(idx);**//I get compilation error in this line
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Child<String> c=new Child<String>();
            c.appendData("Data1");
            c.appendData("Data2");

            c.displayData(1);
        }
    }
```

Solution Updated Class:

```
public class Child<S> extends Parent<String>{

public void appendData(String newItem){
    super.add(newItem);
}
public void displayData(int idx){
    List<String> data=this.getData();
    String s=data.get(idx);
    System.out.println(s);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c=new Child();
    c.appendData("Data1");
    c.appendData("Data2");

    c.displayData(1);
}
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? I assume you want to have `toString()` here `data.get(idx);`.

Comment: You have to cast like this: String s=(String)data.get(idx) otherwise you have to use  List<String> data instead of  List<E> data

Comment: Generics takes care of Type Casting right?

Comment: Child<String> c=new Child<String>(); I have declared like this, It also implies that type argument in data=new ArrayList<E>(); is String. Then why should i do a explicit type casting...

Comment: Should be `E s = data.get(idx)` and then `s instanceof String` would return true, therefore you could do `String s = (String) data.get(idx);`

Comment: You have to explicit type casting because The type of list not  a string thats why

Comment: @Amith Your answer isn't ideal in the sense that he could only have `Child<String>`, and all other types would error.

Comment: @Josh M I have updated please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't be something hard to understand:

In `String s=data.get(idx);`, `data` is in type of `ArrayList<E>`. Given you have no special restriction in `E`, it is possible to be any type that is NOT a String.  Just think, what will happen if you are using a `Child<Date>`, for which the `data` is in fact an `ArrayList<Date>`, `String s = data.get(i)` simply doesn't make sense.

Hence, compiler complain to you that you cannot simply assume the result of `data.get(index)` to be a String.

The way to fix can be straight-forward.  For example you can do whatever suggested in other people's answer.  It may also be an issue of your design that, your `Child` should not bear type parameter and it should extends from `Parent<String>`.  However it is more important that you understand why it doesn't work, so that you can choose the correct way to fix your problem.

Comment: Updated classpublic class Child<S> extends Parent<String>{

 public void appendData(String newItem){
  super.add(newItem);
 }
 public void displayData(int idx){
  List<String> data=this.getData();
  String s=data.get(idx);
  System.out.println(s);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Child c=new Child();
  c.appendData("Data1");
  c.appendData("Data2");
  
  c.displayData(1);
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

here you go.

```
data.get(idx).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

That line should read:

```
E s = data.get(idx);
```

Then if you want to print it, you can do it like this:

```
System.out.println(s.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to `generics`.  But to answer the question,

```
String s=data.get(idx);
```

should be replaced with

```
String s= String.valueOf( data.get(idx) );
```

If you are absolutely sure that `data.get(idx)` will never return `null`, you can also use:

```
String s= data.get(idx).toString() ;
```

Otherwise, you will receive `NullPointerException`s.

On a second read, you can also use

```
System.out.println( data.get(idx) ) ;
```

directly.  Internally, this uses `String.valueOf()` so it's equally exception-safe.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you get the compilation error is because in the `Child` class, where you call `data.get(idx)` It doesn't know that it's going to be a String.

```
public void displayData(int idx) {
    List<E> data = this.getData();
    //String s=data.get(idx); //Doesn't compile because it won't know this is a String at runtime
    E s = data.get(idx); // To make it generic to the type in main, change the type to E
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem either casting it to string or use string in your generic parameter

```
String s = data.get(idx);
ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Reason you are getting this error because you are using Generic methods and type parameter 
So when you are assigning value from your generic list to a string you are getting error. Compiler does not know that your List actually contains string data.